# Using iptables to stop brute force attacks on a Apache https site

Tags: iptables, apache-httpd, ssl

I have a TLS site Apache which uses Basic Authentication to protect resources.

I'm trying to setup an iptables rule to prevent brute force attacks on port 443, so I've added the following iptables rules in a bash script.

```
$IPTABLES -N SSL-Brute-Force
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j SSL-Brute-Force
$IPTABLES -A SSL-Brute-Force -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSL --rsource
$IPTABLES -A SSL-Brute-Force -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 5 --name SSL --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "[SSL Brute Force] "
$IPTABLES -A SSL-Brute-Force -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 5 --name SSL --rsource -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A SSL-Brute-Force -j ACCEPT
```

Now I can't access my site at all, and I can't see every packet to port 443 being dropped in my messages file.

Did I get these rules right?

Answer (score 1):

No. Replace the `--update` options with `--rcheck`; the appearance update already happens with `--set`. With `--update` the same packet causes up to three updates as it advances through the rules. In particular, it may well match the `DROP` rule without having matched the `LOG` rule, since each one increments the hit count.

Changing to `--rcheck` should open it to allow you to view one web page with, say, a style sheet and three images every 10 minutes.

It's worth to note that every separate component (style sheet, javascript, images and frames) of the page causes a new connection. Thus, you may need to also change `5` to something higher depending on the degree of decomposition in your web pages. The question is how many pages would a user churn through in 600 seconds, and how many connections does each page need.